# Angular only loads first directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have declared two directives by the following design pattern:

```
var sampleDrtv = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/sample.html',
        link: function() {
            alert('sample');
        }
    }
};

angular
.module('app')
.directive('sampleDrtv', sampleDrtv);
```

**If I add two directives following this pattern, only the first one gets loaded.
Can someone explain me why?**

Code Snippet: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doYKap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tags are not properly closed. As the result Angular can't parse directives correctly. Fixed HTML would be:

```
<div ng-app="ativ">
    <ativ-history-list></ativ-history-list>
    <ativ-history-detail></ativ-history-detail>
</div>
```

Note, that custom elements require closing tags, they are not self-closing.

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdYZqG

Answer (score 2):

Currently your html has `<ativ-history-list/><ativ-history-list/>` which seems to be wrong, you treated those html tags as they have self closing tags. Because they are not closed properly only one element is getting render on UI second element getting neglected.

Elements tag shouldn't be closed using `/` unless the elements are like `<area />`,`<base />`,`<br />`
,`<col />`,`<command />`
,`<embed />`,`<hr />`
,`<img />`,`<input />`
,`<keygen />`,`<link />`,
`<meta />`,`<param />`
`<source />`,`<track />`,
`<wbr />`, etc.

Customize element created for directive should have been closed properly

```
  <ativ-history-list> </ativ-history-list>
  <ativ-history-detail></ativ-history-list>
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbjxRZ)

Comment: @ghuroo glad to help you..man :) to look at my edit.. in which I explained in details why it was not working..As you asked in your question

Comment: live and learn ;) i thought any tag could be self-closing. thanks once again.

Comment: @ghuroo do you want anything else.? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

While creating directives as elements close them properly. They are not self closing.

```
<div ng-app="ativ">
    <ativ-history-list></ativ-history-list>
    <ativ-history-detail></ativ-history-detail>
</div>
```